# SCSS compiler not working properly in PyCharm

Tags: css, sass, pycharm, jetbrains-ide, file-watcher

I am trying to set up a SCSS transpiler in PyCharm for Django project.

Basically, what I need is to convert `/static/scss/main.scss` to `/static/css/main.css`

Here are the configurations of SCSS File Watcher:

```
Program: /home/maverick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/scss

Arguments: --no-cache --update /home/maverick/Documents/DjangoProjects/timberg/static/css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css

Working directory: /home/maverick/Documents/DjangoProjects/timberg/static/scss

Output paths to refresh: /home/maverick/Documents/DjangoProjects/timberg/static/css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css
```

What is happening is that `main.css` is being generated where it should. But it contains only errors, not the expected css, like this:

```
/*
Error: Inconsistent indentation: 2 spaces were used for indentation,    but the rest of the document was indented using 8 spaces.
    on line 39 of    /home/maverick/Documents/DjangoProjects/timberg/static/css/main.css
```

and etc.

What is wrong here? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the `Arguments` part.

It should be:

```
$FileName$:/home/maverick/Documents/DjangoProjects/timberg/static/css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css
```

not just:

```
/home/maverick/Documents/DjangoProjects/timberg/static/css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css
```

My mistake was leaving out `$FileName$:` at the beginning.